# Messed up my 12.04 graphics: Falsely installed NVidia drivers on HD Graphics

Tags: 12.04, graphics, intel-graphics

OK hope you can help. After installing Ubuntu 12.04 I noticed that my graphics were sluggish so I decided to install the new NVidia drivers. Wrongly I assumed I needed NVidia drivers. Stupid mistake, my laptop has a Intel HD Graphics driver.

Damage is done. Computer is stuck in 640x480 and I can't change it. I removed the Nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

And tried installing `mesa-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Still nothing. Please help.

Comment: When you say you accidentally installed Nvidia drivers on HD graphics, I think you mean this is another hybrid/optimus question.  Is that the case?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work

Comment: I think you all misunderstood.  He installed nVidia drivers while running an intel HD Graphics card.  He wants to figure out how to undo the damage and get the Intel card working right again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-installing (or install if missing)

[xserver-xorg-video-intel [image: Install xserver-xorg-video-intel]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xserver-xorg-video-intel)

These are the drivers for Intel, hopefully a re-install will fix the settings that Nvidia borked.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. I tried installing xserver-xorg-video-intel, but couldn't (apt-get told me it was already the latest version). So I figured, what if I remove it and reinstall? I removed it, rebooted and actually was fine again. Don't know why, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: it worked b/c Nvidia reset all the video settings and likely broke some libraries.  It may have been possible to fix everything one by one but this was a fast and dirty fix and alot easier.  Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Also: If you install these libraries it will allow you to get the texture compression libraries needed for mesa to run some of the higher quality games, they are not included due to a copyright issue(this of course assumes your graphic card is strong enough, works well for most of them on my Sandy Bridge)`libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0`